# Converting string to datetime object -- '2020-11-16' to a date

Tags: python, datetime

I have a date as a string like this: `2020-11-16`

I am trying to convert it to a date using `datetime.strptime(date(str), formatting)`.

My current formatting is this: `%Y/%m/%d`

I receive this error:

```
time data '2020-11-16' does not match format '%Y/%m/%d'
```

Comment: You can try using date.fromisoformat('2020-11-16')

Comment: Format doesn’t match. What is not clear about the error message? hyphens don’t match slashes.

Answer (score 0):

Simply change the `%Y/%m/%d` format to `%Y-%m-%d` format:

```
from datetime import datetime

s = '2020-11-16'
d = datetime.strptime(s, '%Y-%m-%d')

print(d)
```

Prints:

```
2020-11-16 00:00:00
```